# Angular: check an observable that may return null inside switchmap

Tags: angular, switchmap

how to handle the nullity case within a switchmap operator ?
I found this workaround, but I get the impression it’s not great to do this:

```
   this.userService
  .getApporteurId()
  .pipe(
    switchMap((test) =>
      test ? this.mesQuotasService.getQuotas(test) : of({})
    )
  )
  .subscribe((quotas: any) => console.log(quotas));
```

}

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

I am prefer to use filter operator before switchMap like this:

```
this.userService
  .getApporteurId()
  .pipe(
    filter(test => !!test),
    switchMap((test) => this.mesQuotasService.getQuotas(test))
  )
  .subscribe((quotas: any) => console.log(quotas));
```

Comment: I've tried it, but doesn't work for me...

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz example to better demonstrate what you're suggesting? It would be really helpful to see your code in action and understand how it all fits together.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the current code works, why not.

An alternative is that you may look for [iif](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/iif).

> Subscribe to first or second observable based on a condition

```
import { iif } from 'rxjs';

this.userService
  .getApporteurId()
  .pipe(
    switchMap((test) =>
      iif(() => !!test, this.mesQuotasService.getQuotas(test), of({})
    )
  )
  .subscribe((quotas: any) => console.log(quotas));
}
```